QGIS: DB Manager query returns data, but when I load the layer the attribute fields are empty
I'm querying data in DB Manager and my query works (see attached image) and when I load it in as a layer the geometry displays properly, but the layer's attribute table is empty (see second image). It states that there are 764 total features (which I want) but that 0 of them are filtered. Any reason why this is happening? 


Try ticking Column(s) with unique values and set it.
